# In SDL 9.6 (dev environment) during publishing receiving error while "creating bean with name 'TridionUnzipStep'"

Tags: core-service, sdl-tridion, dynamic-linking, dynamic-publishing

Trying to publish a set of a few static/dynamic components in Tridion Sites 9.6 DEV environment. During publishing, receiving the error "creating bean with name 'TridionUnzipStep'" frequently. This issue mostly occurred during the publishing of dynamic components.

I am attaching a sample snippet of error logs below.

```
ERROR [deployer-combined-service,------,development,live] 14 --- [eue)-6-thread-5] c.s.d.d.w.queue.imp
l.CommandQueuePoller  : Could not process command: JSONCommand{verbs=[Content], action='TridionBootstrap', binaryIds=[XXX-XXXXX-XX.Content.zip], executionId='XXX:X-XXXXXX-XXXXX', properties={}}
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'TridionUnzipStep': Singleton bean cr
eation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method i
mplementation!)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:319)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:616)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:604)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1227)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.step.SpringAwareExecutableStepFactory.resolveExecutableStep(SpringAwareExecutableStepFactory.java
:49)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.step.SpringAwareExecutableStepFactory.create(SpringAwareExecutableStepFactory.java:38)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.step.BasicExecutableStepFactoryManager.getStep(BasicExecutableStepFactoryManager.java:44)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.execute(StepActor.scala:67)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.com$sdl$delivery$deployer$engine$pipeline$actor$StepActor$$processStep(S
tepActor.scala:58)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(StepActor.scala:41)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:539)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:537)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.aroundReceive(StepActor.scala:27)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:614)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:583)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:268)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:229)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Can someone please suggest any workaround on above issue!.

Comment: Are you experiencing stability issues with  deployer service? The error seems to point in the direction of the deployer being shut down while a deployment is in progress.

Comment: I agree with Quirijn. If your statement of `This issue mostly occurred during the publishing of dynamic components.` is correct - and it's not happening all the time with dynamic components (or batches where dynamic components are included) then I'd be switching up the log-level and looking some more at the deployer.

Simple things to test ... is it when publishing over 'x' items; is it when others are publishing so the publish throughput is higher; is it related to the size of the items being published (remembering that DCPs often trigger larger publish tasks);

Comment: assuming there's no custom coding involved here also.

Comment: Thank you so much for your inputs. we made some modification in configuration. we got below logs;
2023-02-22 06:50:36.135 ERROR [deployer-combined-service,xxxxxxxx,development,live] 13 --- [eue)-6-thread-4] c.s.d.d.w.queue.imp
l.CommandQueuePoller  : Could not process command: JSONCommand{verbs=[Content], action='TridionBootstrap', binaryIds=[tcm_x-xxxxxxxx-xx
xxx.Content.zip], executionId='tcm:x-xxxxxxxx-xxxxx', properties={}}
java.lang.InterruptedException: null

Comment: CommandQueuePoller  : Could not process command: JSONCommand{verbs=[Content], action='TridionBootstrap', binaryIds=[tcm_X-XXXXXXX-XX
xxx.Content.zip], executionId='tcm:X-XXXXXXX-XX
xxx', properties={}}java.lang.InterruptedException: null at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1040) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1345) at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:242)

Comment: If you are having a different issue, please consider editing your question with more detail, or creating a new question.

Comment: @Shrikant_P are you still facing issue , do you have any extension or you installed OOTB deployer. you mention the items are facing only when you publish dynamic components , are you still publishing items to both file system and broker. Please try to capture the DEBIG logs   see of you fine more information

Comment: refer to https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000019810 for similar issue,  see hotfix Tridion Sites 9.6: CD_11.6.0_31557